# Interface issue in the script editor of the Dbeaver

Tags: database-administration, dbeaver

I tried to find a solution for this issue but i couldn't. Whenever I try to execute a query, the editor generates multiple scroll bars which overlap my script. Well, a picture is worth a thousand words:
**(I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and my Dbeaver version is 5.1.4)**

[image]

Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: UPDATE: this issue happens after computer hibernation